# Detecting DOM Object injection in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, dom, xss, phantomjs

I am trying to find a way to detect DOM injection to detect Cross Site Scripting. I found DOM Mutation functions such as `DOMNodeInsertedIntoDocument` and `DOMNodeInserted` which I can use to detect DOM injection if the DOM manipulation is done via JS.

But I need to find if a new DOM object is inserted into the document, which didn't exist before when the browser parsing the HTML at page load. Is this feasible only using JavaScript? I need to achieve this using PhantomJS if feasible. Can anybody give me a solution(atleast an idea) if there is one?

Thank you.

Comment: How could something get injected after page load other than via JS?

Comment: What's the real need ? I hope it's unrelated to security ?

Comment: @Barmar, like this. If a page contains a Search field which is vulnerable to XSS attack and when we type something and search, the search query is reflected on the browser? If someone try to reflect a javascript or any other element, I need to detect that javascript/element injection.

Comment: I was going to suggest mutation observers  ([spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/dom/#mutation-observers), [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver)), but sadly although PhantomJS is WebKit-based and most WebKit-based browsers support mutation observers, PhantomJS [doesn't yet](https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/issues/10715).

Comment: If we're searching using AJAX, that's JS modifying the page. If it's a normal form submission, the page is reloaded from scratch, so anything that's inserted is in the HTML at page load time.

Comment: @Barmar, Definitely. I need to detect any new changes in the page (compared to last version) when the page is reloaded from scratch.

Comment: Save the entire contents of the document in `localStorage`. When the page reloads, compare the current contents to the version in localStorage. But aren't differences expected, such as the results of the search?

Comment: Yup. I just took an example. In my case, there is no other changes in the page. Isn't there a way to compare these two pages for any new DOM objects keeping the page only in memory rather than accessing local storage.